# PictureBox Show and Dispose

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to show a `PictureBox` on button click, this should be on first click Show `PictureBox`, and on next click Hide `PictureBox`, again on third click show `PictureBox` and similar on fourth click again hide the `PictureBox`.

I have tried below code but it stuck after dispose of picture.

```
public bool i;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!i)
    {
        m1();
        i = true;
    }
    else
    {
        m2();
        i = false;
    }    
}

public void m1()
{
    pictureBox1.Show();
}

public void m2()
{
    pictureBox1.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: You need to tell us what technbology your using? Win/Web forms by the looks of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pictureBox.Visible = true;


 pictureBox.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to `Dispose` your `PictureBox`. Just set the [visibility](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.visible(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    pictureBox1.Visible = !pictureBox1.Visible;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is for Winforms? Calling Dispose will destroy the picturebox object in memory so that is why you are having the issue.

Use:

```
// Show the picture box
pictureBox.Visible = true;

// Hide the picture box 
pictureBox.Visible = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
// Show the picture box
pictureBox.Visible = true;

// Hide the picture box 
pictureBox.Visible = false;
```